# Need guidance in dealing with TCL regexp

Tags: regex, tcl

I need to process a random string which has the character ".." in-between. Like the one shown below

```
a..b/c..de/f-g..xyz..abc..def..123..
```

How can I get the data between these ".." using regexp?( this string can be of any length and I need to get each intermediate data set for further processing). Please guide me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: So you want `a`, `b/c`, `de/f-g`, `xyz`, `abc`, `def` and `123`?

Comment: Yes, I want those data and the string length is unknown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is p.e. no newline in the string you could get a list of your strings with:

```
set in a..b/c..de/f-g..xyz..abc..def..123..
set out [split [string map {.. \n} $in] \n]]
```

Comment: A good character to map-to/split-on is `\ufffc` (the “object replacement character”) since you're really unlikely to encounter one of those in any real text.

Answer (score 1):

One tool to consider for this sort of thing, especially if the splitting term is more complex than the one in the question, is [the `textutil::split` package in Tcllib](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/textutil_split.html). That lets you split strings by regular expression, like this:

```
package require textutil::split

set sample "a..b/c..de/f-g..xyz..abc..def..123.."
set RE {\.\.};  # “.” is an RE metacharacter, and so needs to be escaped
set pieces [textutil::split::splitx $sample $RE]
```

The above will also produce an empty element at the end of the `pieces` list, because there's a terminating separator.

Comment: The regular expression could also be `\.{2}`, but that's hardly simpler, or it could be `***=..` (a leading `***=` is a special Tcl RE engine feature for “just match the rest as a literal”).

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex:

```
[^..]
```

That would match all characters that are not `..`.

Comment: I think this command would probably look at the beginning of the string for ".." and leaves the rest. I tried this and its not producing the required result.

Comment: @Nathan: Actually, that would be a command called `^..`. Or — more relevantly — a regular expression that matches anything except a `.` (because brackets enclose a character _set_).

Comment: @NathanPk When I tested this on `http://regexhero.net/tester/` it grabbed everything that wasn't `..`